# SQL query and string search

Tags: mysql, sql

I have that database diagram (MySQL). Each `Book` has assigned a `BookLanguage`. Each `BookLanguage` has two different `LanguageNames` (the globalization purpose). And also, each `Book` can have an additional `BookLanguage` **(but it's not required)**.

And here's the problem - I'm stuck here while building a SQL query for searching for that `Books`, whose have some string in the `BookLanguageNames`. It's simple to build the query with joining the `BookLanguage` and `BookLanguageNames` but how to cope with the `AdditionalBookLanguages` ?

[image]

Comment: What data do you want returned?  We can't help if we don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to get these Books, whose have some string in the Name column in the BookLanguageNames and also (if exist) in the AdditionalBookLanguages

Comment: What is the `Code` column in the `BookLanguage` table?  Is it necessary?  Why is not in the `BookLanguageNames` or `AdditionalBookLanguages`?

Comment: the Code column is not important in that case

Comment: it's not normalize, additionalbook,book and booklanguage you have a loop, you should create only one relationship between them

Comment: But what, if one Book would have more than one AdditionalBookLanguage ? I think in that case the diagram is OK

Comment: If you get rid of the link between "Book" and "BookLanguage", and put all relationships in your current "AdditionalBookLanguages" (I'd consider renaming that...), then you'd have a normalized database.  Throw a column on there saying "IsPrimaryLanguage" and restrict such that you can only have one primary per book if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simplifying the database design?  Have three tables `Book`, `BookLanguageName` (both of them similar structure to yours) and, instead of `AdditionalBookLanguage` and `BookLanguage` have a "lookup table" - `BookLanguage`:

1. `Book` - here you keep all the information about the books.
2. `BookLanguage` - only three columns: BookID, BookLanguageID (or Code) and a boolean is_additional.  BookID and BookLanguageID would be a composite primary key.
3. `Language` - here you keep all information related to a particular language.

In such case, writing query would be easier.

Comment: sound very interesting, I'll consider that option. Thanks for the idea !

Comment: You're welcome, Tony!  Please let us know later what was your final solution.